# Is their a better structure for collision handling on multiple graphics?

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I am a novice who is working on a simple JavaScript web page that using the processing.js plugin to generated moving graphics.  I have started to work on collision detection and handling.  I examine each graphic and change it's direction if it gets too close to any of the other graphics.  The program is buggy because the graphics eventually have simultaneous collisions on more than one other graphic.  This then creates an interesting (but undesired) effect of getting the graphics "stuck" inside one another.

I could work on a function to detect multiple collisions and handle them in a way that stops the graphical objects from getting inside each other.  However, I feel like their is a more fundamental flaw in my approach.  I don't want to create a band aide solution when their may be a more structural flaw in my collision handling approach.

Should I just write a function that handles the bug of multiple simultaneous collisions or should I go back to the drawing board with program structure?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="lightblue"   style="margin:0;">
<center>
<script src="processing.js"></script>
<script type="application/processing">

int orbNumber = 30;

void setup(){
    h=[];
    float t;
    size(600,600);
    frameRate(60);
    //assign starting variables for floating objects
    for(int a = 0; a < orbNumber; a++){
        h[a] = new orb(0,   200, 1, 64); 
        h[a].xpos = random(1,width);
        h[a].ypos = a * 100;
        h[a].red = random(128,255);
        h[a].blue = random(128,255);
        h[a].green = random(128,255);
        }
}

void draw() { 
    background(200,200,200,0);
    //call the update method from the orb class to calculate postion and display graphic
    for(int a = 0; a < orbNumber; a++)h[a].update(); 

    //number the graphics
    textFont("Arial", 22);
    fill(255,255,255,80);
    for(int a = 0; a < orbNumber; a++)text(a,h[a].xpos-6,h[a].ypos+6); 

    //for each graphic, check distance for each other graphic and change 
    //movement direction upon collisions
    for(int a = 0; a < orbNumber; a++)for(int b = a+1; b < (orbNumber); b++){   
            if(circleCollision(h[a],h[b])){
                t=h[a].xOffset;
                h[a].xOffset=h[b].xOffset;
                h[b].xOffset = t;
                t=h[a].yOffset;
                h[a].yOffset=h[b].yOffset;
                h[b].yOffset = t;
                h[a].update;
                h[b].update;
                h[a].imperfectEdge()
                h[b].imperfectEdge()
            }
        }
} 

function circleCollision(circle1,circle2){
    var x1 = circle1.xpos;
    var x2 = circle2.xpos;
    var y1 = circle1.ypos;
    var y2 = circle2.ypos;
    var distance = sqrt( (x1-x2) * (x1-x2) + (y1-y2) * (y1-y2) );
    var widths = circle1.radius + circle2.radius;
    var t = false;
    if(distance<widths)t = true;
    //text("distance = " + distance,20,20);
    return t;
    }


class orb { 
  float xpos, ypos, speed, diameter, xOffset, yOffset, radius; 
  int red, blue, green;
  orb (float x, float y, float s, float size) {  
    xpos = x;
    ypos = y; 
    diameter = size;
    xOffset = s;
    yOffset = s; 
    radius = .5 * diameter;
    } 


  void update() { 
    ypos += yOffset; 
    xpos += xOffset; 
    if(yOffset<0&&ypos<0+radius){
        yOffset=-yOffset;
        imperfectEdge();
        }
    if(yOffset>0&&ypos>height-radius){
        yOffset=-yOffset;
        imperfectEdge();
        }
    if(xOffset<0&&xpos<0+radius){
        xOffset=-xOffset;
        imperfectEdge();
        }
    if(xOffset>0&&xpos>width-radius){
        xOffset=-xOffset;
        imperfectEdge();
        }
    noStroke();
    for(a = diameter; a > 0; a-=5){
        fill(red-a,blue-a,green-a);
        ellipse(xpos, ypos, a, a); 
        }
  } 
  void imperfectEdge(){
    xOffset=xOffset+random(-.1,.1);
    yOffset=yOffset+random(-.1,.1);
  }

}
</script><canvas></canvas> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about you first find all collisions, store it in some variable of the circles (array of colliding circles or something), and then calculate the resulting reaction for each circle?

Comment: I see what you mean.  I should find all of the collisions and evaluate the data for a single adjustment rather than letting each object react separately.  Thanks!